# Javascript Common Tasks Form Library

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm interesting if somebody knows a library with common tasks when manipulating forms, I need some advanced tasks like conditional selectors that display/hide other fields, cloning fields, reset child selectors when parent selector changes, add options to selectors dinamically, etc.

I already have custom functions using jquery to do some of those tasks but are not "portable", since I made it for an specific app and I guess there are better ways to do that than those I did.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [jQuery Validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation).

I didn't realize it before but there are quite a lot of things you can do with it. It's portable, and will help you to achieve a lot of the more custom needs of your forms.

Comment: Thanks. I already used the jQuery Validation plugin and it only covers the validation issues. I need something for working with dynamic forms.